# Как я могу обойти CloudFlare на этом сайте?

Tags: python, requests, cloudflare

Сайт: pathofexile.ru
Хочу сделать мониторинг предметов и т.д.

```
    s = requests.Session()
    s.cookies.set('POESESSID', POESSID, domain='pathofexile.com', path='/')

    body = s.get('https://ru.pathofexile.com/my-account').text
    soup = bs(body, 'html.parser')
    check_ = soup.find('div', {'class':'profile-boxes'})
    if check_ != None:
        print('[POE] CloudFlare :(')
    else:
        open('body.html','w+', encoding='utf-8').write(body)
        return
```

Как мне обойти этот CloudFlare?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно передавать заголовок User-Agent и исполнять на клиенте javascript.
Ваш способ для этого не подходит. Используйте Selenium webdriver.